# Uploadify and Rails without using Rack Middleware, CarrierWave or Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, uploadify

The project that I'm working on needs to upload videos to S3.  It uses jQuery so it looks like Uploadify will work the best.  The only problem is that we're not using the Rack gem, CarrierWave or Paperclip and I don't want to have to add any of those with their dependencies just to get this to work.  Every example that I've found so far uses one of those though, is there any way to get Uploadify to work without Rack, CarrierWave or Paperclip?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently, no there isn't.  Looks like I'm going to be using Paperclip